# Jquery to merge almost similar call together

Tags: jquery, keypress

I got a login form which has a button that is click to call ajax request, the request is trigger only if i mouse clicked on the button instead of press the enter key,

```
<form id="signin_form">
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <input type="button" id="btn_signin" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

I found a working sample from here (thanks to Stackoverflow) by how to make it on keypress, below is almost the same reaction, can below scripts merge together in order to make the scripts clean?

```
$("#password").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'loginRequest',
            type: 'POST',
            data: parameters,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output_str){
                if(output_str == "success"){

                    window.location.replace(window.location);
                }else{
                    $('#result').html(output_str);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

// login request
$('#btn_signin').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + '/login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_str){
            if(output_str == "success"){

                window.location.replace(window.location);
            }else{
                $('#result').html(output_str);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#password").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#btn_signin').click();
    }
});

// login request
$('#btn_signin').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + '/login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_str){
            if(output_str == "success"){

                window.location.replace(window.location);
            }else{
                $('#result').html(output_str);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are asking for

```
$("#password").keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                performLogin();
            }
        });

    // login request
    $('#btn_signin').click(function () {
        var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();
        performLogin();
    });

    function performLogin() {
        var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + '/login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: parameters,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (output_str) {
                if (output_str == "success") {

                    window.location.replace(window.location);
                } else {
                    $('#result').html(output_str);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind both events to the same function, and check for clicks or enter key, like so:

```
$("#password").on('keypress click', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'click' || event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'loginRequest',
            type: 'POST',
            data: parameters,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output_str){
                if(output_str == "success"){
                    window.location.replace(window.location);
                }else{
                    $('#result').html(output_str);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc3EU/).

In essence it comes down to using the submit handler which fires when you **click the submit button** and when you **press enter in any of the form fields**. Just as you would expect from a form.

Can not be cleaner and communicate better what you're doing.

```
$("form").submit(function () {        
    // Your ajax code here...

    return false;
});
```

In order for this to work change your input type from 'button' to 'submit'.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using keypress and click, you can achieve both form submission functionality with a single .submit() function. You would have to chane your `<input type="button" id="btn_signin" value="Sign In">` to `<input type="submit" id="btn_signin" value="Sign In">`

```
$("#password").submit(function(){

var parameters = $('#signin_form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'loginRequest',
            type: 'POST',
            data: parameters,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output_str){
                if(output_str == "success"){

                    window.location.replace(window.location);
                }else{
                    $('#result').html(output_str);
                }
            }
        });

});
```